# Angular data from service not showing on the frontend

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Ive made 3 views and linked them to a single controller. In my controller, I am calling a service which I have made which makes a network call and gets some data which I am supposed to display on the frontend. The trouble is, that it is not showing this data despite me doing everything properly.

This is how the structure looks.

Routes:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.view1', {
    url: '/view1',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/testModule/views/view1.html',
    controller: 'testModuleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      InitialData: authResolver
    }


  }).state('app.view2', {
    url: '/view2',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/testModule/views/view2.html',
    controller: 'testModuleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      InitialData: authResolver
    }


  }).state('app.view3', {
    url: '/view3',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/testModule/views/view3.html',
    controller: 'testModuleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      InitialData: authResolver
    }


  })
```

Controller:

```
    (function () {
   'use strict';

  angular
    .module('com.module.testModule')
    .controller('testModuleCtrl', testModuleCtrl);

  testModuleCtrl.$inject = ['$state','$rootScope','UserService', '$stateParams', 'ReportService','SharedDataService','BlogService',
'toastr', 'InitialData', 'SharedFunctionService'];
  function testModuleCtrl($state, $rootScope, UserService, $stateParams, ReportService, SharedDataService,BlogService,
                     toastr, InitialData, SharedFunctionService) {
    var vm = this;

     vm.getUserData = getUserData;




     vm.goToPage1 = goToPage1;
     vm.goToPage2 = goToPage2;
    vm.goToPage3 = goToPage3;

function goToView1(){
  $state.go('app.view1');
  getUserData("someArg");


}

function goToView2(){

  console.log("Going to View 2")
  $state.go('app.view2');
  getUserData("someArg");


}

function goToView3(){
  console.log("Going to View 3")
  $state.go('app.reportView3');


}

function getUserData(argumentType) {
  ReportService.GetTestReport("someArg").then(function reportSuccessCallback(result) {
    vm.result = result.data;
    console.log("CHECK OUT THIS RAD RESULT, BRO ----> ");
        console.log(vm.result);
          }, function reportErrorCallback(reason) {
        vm.reason = reason.data;
        console.log("The reason of failure is this --=> ")
        console.log(vm.reason);
      })
    } 
    }  
    })();
```

In the html, I am trying to render this result by doing 
    {{ vm.result }}

but it is not showing. I am managing the scope too. Doing everything as prescribed in the John-Papa Style guidelines for Angular 1.x

Ive been on this since morning and I am about to pull my hair out. What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to everything in a very optimized manner. 
Ps. New Here.

EDIT: 
As per request, I am adding the service code too.

Service

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('com.module.tests')
    .factory('ReportService', ReportService);

  ReportService.$inject = ['$http','ENV'];
  function ReportService($http,ENV) {

    var baseUrl=ENV.apiUrl+'/tests/';

    var service = {

  GetTestReport: GetTestReport

};

return service;



function GetTestReport(type){
  return $http.get(baseUrl + type + '/testReport').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}




// private functions

function handleSuccess(res) {
  return res.data;
}

function handleError() {
  return {success: false}
}

  }

})();
```

Comment: Can you show me the code in your ReportService please.

Comment: Hello @Arno_Geismar I added the service code in the question. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the above code is the **execution flow.**

First you are using `$state.go()` to navigate to the different view and after that you are calling  `getUserData()`.

So first you have navigated to the new view and the corresponding controller(weather you are using same controller or different controller for multiple views) has different scope.

> *To overcome that you can pass the value as state params to route and in controller pick that state params from route and call `getUserData`
>   with that value.*

Routes:

```
$stateProvider
   .state('app.view1', {
      // Append query parameters here in the url.

      url: '/view1?q',
      templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/testModule/views/view1.html',
      controller: 'testModuleCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {
         InitialData: authResolver
      }
   }).state('app.view2', {
      // Append query parameters here in the url.

      url: '/view2?q',
      templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/testModule/views/view2.html',
      controller: 'testModuleCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {
        InitialData: authResolver
      }
   }).state('app.view3', {
      // Append query parameters here in the url.

      url: '/view3?q',
      templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/testModule/views/view3.html',
      controller: 'testModuleCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {
        InitialData: authResolver
      }
   });
```

In your controller:

```
(function () {

   'use strict';

   angular
    .module('com.module.testModule')
    .controller('testModuleCtrl', testModuleCtrl);

    testModuleCtrl.$inject = ['$state','$stateParams', 'ReportService', 'InitialData'];

    function testModuleCtrl($state, $stateParams, ReportService, InitialData) {

         var vm = this;

         vm.getUserData = getUserData;

         vm.goToPage1 = goToPage1;
         vm.goToPage2 = goToPage2;
         vm.goToPage3 = goToPage3;

         // Here check weather the params is passed on route
         if(typeof $stateParams.q !== "undefined" && $stateParams.q !== '')  {
               // load the data using service by passing params
               getUserData($stateParams.q);
         }



         function goToView1(){ 
             $state.go("app.view1", {q:'someArg'});
         }

         function goToView2() {
             $state.go("app.view2", {q:'someArg'});
         }

         function goToView3(){
             $state.go('app.reportView3', {q: 'someArg'});
         }

         function getUserData(query) {
              // Your service code to load the data based on "query".

              ReportService.GetTestReport(query).then(function(result) {
                 vm.result = result.data;
              }, function(reason) {
                 vm.reason = reason.data;
              });
         } 
     }  
})();
```

In your service GetTestReport method

```
   function GetTestReport(type){
       // return promise directly
       return $http.get(baseUrl + type + '/testReport');
   }
```

Comment: Hey @jaguwalapratik .. I dont think I understand. Can you please show it to me, as in, how to do it. Ive just picked up Angular and and trying to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that are wrong:

service declaration:

```
function GetTestReport(type){
  return $http.get(baseUrl + type + '/testReport').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}
```

you should change it to :

```
function GetTestReport(type, handleSuccess, handleError){
  return $http.get(baseUrl + type + '/testReport').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}
```

then where you are calling it do this:

```
ReportService.GetTestReport("someArg", function(result){
    vm.result = result.data;
    console.log(vm.result);
}, function(error){
    vm.reason = reason.data;
    console.log(vm.reason);
});
```

You can also fetch data from your service before your state has finished loading by doing this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.view1', {
    url: '/view1',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/testModule/views/view1.html',
    controller: 'testModuleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      InitialData: authResolver,
      YourResult: function(ReportService) {
            return ReportService.GetTestReport().$promise
      }
    }
```

you should change your service to the following then:

```
function GetTestReport(type){
      return $http.get(baseUrl + type + '/testReport');
}
```

then in vm controller you can wire YourResult by doing this:

```
.controller("vm", function(YourResult, InitialData){
// your controller logic
}
```